# Ember: how to translate a placeholder using i18n lib?

Tags: ember.js

See: http://jsfiddle.net/cyclomarc/36VS3/1/

I am using Ember i18n lib for translations.  How can I use a translated string in an Ember.TextField view ?

Idem for textarea view and select view.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2>Ember Translate placeholder</h2>
    {{t T1005}}<br>
    {{view Ember.TextField placeholder="T1005"}}
</script>
```

The placeholder in the input field should also say 'Info' and thus not 'T1005' (being the reference of the string).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could also do it this way, by adding the `Ember.I18n.TranslateableAttributes` mixin to the views that need to be translation aware, like this:

```
Ember.TextField.reopen(Ember.I18n.TranslateableAttributes)
```

And then add the suffix `Translation` to the properties you want to be translation aware:

```
{{view Ember.TextField placeholderTranslation="T1005"}}
```

See here your updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/36VS3/3/).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Perfect solution. I was not aware that you could use the i18n translateable attributes.  Probably a misisng piece of documentation ?

Comment: I just had a look, it's documented here: https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n look under **Translate properties on any object**

Comment: Bad reading from myself :( - I have looked into this readme multiple times but overlooked the important section about translateable properties.

Answer (score 4):

This will work to translate any attribute, not just the placeholder attribute.

**Translation file:**

```
{
    accounts:{
        emailAddress:'Email Address'
    }
}
```

**Handlebars/Ember** markup:

```
{{input type="email" placeholder=(t 'accounts.emailAddress') }}
```

**Standard** markup

```
<input name="email" placeholder=(t 'login.email-placeholder')>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should probably subclass `Ember.TextField` and add the placeholder as computed property:

```
App.TextField = Ember.TextField.extend({
    placeholder : function(){
        return Ember.I18n.t("T1005");
    }.property()
});
```

And use the following in your handlebars template:

```
{{view App.TextField}}
```

Comment: Could indeed work like this (but then need to pass the variable T1005 from the textfield to the extended textfield via a new property), but there seems to be a solution included in the i18n lib (see answer from @intuitivepixel).

Answer (score 0):

for me works, as described here:
https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n/wiki/Doc:-Translating-Text

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2>Ember Translate placeholder</h2>
    {{t T1005}}<br>
    {{view Ember.TextField placeholder=(t "T1005")}}
</script>
```