# How to build a multilingual ember application

Tags: ember.js

What are the accepted practices in ember to build multilingual applications? What I would like to know is:

- how to make the templates language aware. Is there a way to simplify this, appart from duplicating each template for each of the supported languages?
- how to make the javascript code multilingual? This is more of a generic javascript question, but maybe there is some ember-specific (controllers / models / views ...) advice. As a generic javascript approach, I like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5664675/647991) solution, maybe somebody can comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could roll your own if you need something special, but as a starting point this is what most people use at the moment: https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n

One of (my) favorite feature is clearly the `TranslatteableProperties` mixin which is really easy to use:

> Translate properties on any object:
>   The Em.I18n.TranslateableProperties mixin automatically translates any property ending in "Translation":

```
var userButton = Em.Object.extend(Em.I18n.TranslateableProperties, {
  labelTranslation: 'button.add_user.title'
});

userButton.get('label');
```

Check also this other answer of my: [Ember: how to translate a placeholder using i18n lib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18067342/ember-how-to-translate-a-placeholder-using-i18n-lib) for reference.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, this works very well. Not sure if this will satisfy all my requirements, but it is very easy to use.